# Kotlin string split with readLine() method

Tags: java, kotlin

So I have this Java code:

```
String values = input.nextLine();
String[] longs = values.split(" ");
```

Which splits the string input into a string array.

I try it in Kotlin

```
var input: String? = readLine()
var ints: List<String>? = input.split(" ".toRegex())
```

and I get an error:
"Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of the the type String?"

I am new to Kotlin and would like some clarity on how to do this. Thank you!

Comment: You should read the documentation about [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a look at `readLine()` it reveals that it might return `null`:

```
/**
 * Reads a line of input from the standard input stream.
 *
 * @return the line read or `null` if the input stream is redirected to a file and the end of file has been reached.
 */
public fun readLine(): String? = stdin.readLine()
```

Therefore it's not safe to call `split` on its result, you have to handle the `null` case, e.g. as follows:

```
val input: String? = readLine()
val ints: List<String>? = input?.split(" ".toRegex())
```

Other alternatives and further information can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html).

Comment: Indeed, using `!!` is almost never the answer. Propagating nullability gives you a chance to handle any unexpected errors gracefully.

Comment: Updated. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Look, you code is almost right, just missed the `!!` this ensure that the string should not be empty (it will throw a error). You code should be like this:

```
val input: String? = readLine()
var ints: List<String>? = input!!.split(" ".toRegex())
```

Note that I just added `!!` operator and change `var` to `val` on line 1, because your  input should not be changed (it was given by the user).

Comment: Thank you! That makes my code much cleaner than adding an if statement checking if it is null.

Comment: Question: what does the !! operator do? Is it basically a catch/throw for nulls?

Comment: @KevinPatrick, to answer your question, it does more than assert non-nullness; it also casts the expression to the left to a non-null type. It can also cast ambiguous types from calls to Java methods (e.g. a java function might return a `String!` which means "could be either a `String?` or a `String`") to a definite non-null type

Comment: I think a more correct answer would be to replace the `!!` with the safe navigation operator `?.`, because `ints` is a nullable type and  `?.` will return null if `input` is null, whereas `!!` will throw an exception if `input` is null, never resulting in a null being assigned to `ints`

Comment: If you want to see NullpointerException at runtime, go ahead and use !!

Comment: It is not to see NPE, it is to prevent that the String should not be null, think in a program that the user input can be null? will you program continue running with a entry null?

Comment: Even if you have nothing left to do if the input is bad, you can at least provide a sensible error about it rather than crash the program.